# How to connect 2 input shafts which will work independently to an output shaft

Tags: mechanical-engineering, power-transmission, lifting

I am an undergraduate student in mechanical engineering. One of our professors project is to design a ski lift. A problem my team came across is how to connect the diesel and the electric engine into the pulley-rope system. We have 2 inputs and 1 output, but the inputs need to work separately (the electric engine will be the main engine, but in case something happens the diesel engine needs to start). I think about using a gear box or something similar, is there anything that can be used for this problem?

Comment: think of a differential from a rear wheel drive vehicle ... drive the two axles with the motors

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

1. the motors drive hydraulic pumps as input, output is from a hydraulic motor - if swash plate ones are chosen then input and output can be controlled from zero to max.
2. a differential can be used as 2 in one out.

Bendix or oneway clutches may help.

3. epicyclic gearbox could also be used.